# Convert Buttons and labels to Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

My Org is planning to convert to **Lightning Experience**. Is there any way (like some automation tool) to convert all the buttons and labels to lightning or I have to manually write code ?

Comment: You have to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons that do not use JavaScript can be used in lightning automatically.

But you will need to align the buttons in your page (in the page layout section for lightning buttons) - not all of them are in the same place.

Labels are the same and you don't need any migration.

And about converting automatically your JavaScript buttons - that is impossible, usually the logic of the button should be implemented as a lightning component consumed as a lightning action (unless you can convert this button to a URL or other button that does not need JavaScript).